# Git Failing to remove with clean

Tags: git, repository

when I type in `git clean -f` i get the following error message:

```
>     Removing .__afs043
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs043
>     Removing .__afs0F7D
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs0F7D
>     Removing .__afs1359
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs1359
>     Removing .__afs1421
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs1421
>     Removing .__afs243A
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs243A
>     Removing .__afs2745
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs2745
>     Removing .__afs3454
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs3454
>     Removing .__afs3D12
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs3D12
>     Removing .__afs4A5E
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs4A5E
>     Removing .__afs4FB8
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs4FB8
>     Removing .__afs5D5B
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs5D5B
>     Removing .__afs5E1D
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs5E1D
>     Removing .__afs6086
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs6086
>     Removing .__afs6328
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs6328
>     Removing .__afs6D97
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs6D97
>     Removing .__afs7562
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs7562
>     Removing .__afs7C22
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs7C22
>     Removing .__afs8148
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs8148
>     Removing .__afs865F
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs865F
>     Removing .__afs8CE5
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs8CE5
>     Removing .__afs9295
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs9295
>     Removing .__afs938C
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs938C
>     Removing .__afs9439
>     warning: failed to remove .__afs9439
>     Removing .__afsA5EC
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsA5EC
>     Removing .__afsA859
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsA859
>     Removing .__afsB044
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsB044
>     Removing .__afsB9EF
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsB9EF
>     Removing .__afsC47E
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsC47E
>     Removing .__afsCF6E
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsCF6E
>     Removing .__afsD42
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsD42
>     Removing .__afsD50F
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsD50F
>     Removing .__afsE6B9
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsE6B9
>     Removing .__afsE9F3
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsE9F3
>     Removing .__afsF0DA
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsF0DA
>     Removing .__afsF9EA
>     warning: failed to remove .__afsF9EA
```

from the command. Yet i need to remove these files in order to checkout of my branch because I get the following message:

```
Error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
by checkout:
          .__afs4FB8
          .__afs6D97
          .__afs865F
          .__afs9439
          .__afsF9EA Please move or remove them before you can switch branches. 

Aborting
```

What do I do??! I need to be able to checkout and update this branch fast!

Comment: Are those files/folders able to be removed by your user ID? Do you have permissions to remove them?

Comment: @rainecc i don't know, they are hidden, I can see them, but I don't know how to remove them

Comment: @uDaY , no I am on Red Hat linux

Answer (score 10):

Try `sudo git clean -f`. You probably need elevated rights.

Answer (score 5):

Since `git clean` is refusing to remove these untracked files, try removing them manually by doing

```
rm -f ._afs4FB8 ._afs6D97 ._afs865F ._afs9439 .__afsF9E
```

This should either remove the files or give you a more helpful error message.

Comment: when i try and do that, i get the error "rm: cannot remove `.__afs043': Device or resource busy "

Comment: however, I haven't seen these hidden file types before when using git so I don't really now what to do to end their lifetimes or to get rid of them

Comment: I think there is a program/process running. I would like to close all the windows or programs that use it & try it.

Comment: `fuser .__afs043` will tell you the PID of the process using that file so you can `kill` it.

Comment: thank you.  I actually just closed vim and they went away, so they probably had to do with that running (or my internet which i also temporarily closed).  quite annoying! and dont know why they ended up there!

Comment: Judging by the name, they may have be temporary artifacts of the Andrew File System (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) which are managed by the kernel.  Next time try moving them to a directory outside the git directory (but on the same file system).

Answer (score 3):

You need to check permissions on the files AND the containing folder. If the files have write permission then the folder most likely does not.

`chmod u+w .` while inside the folder. Then `git clean --force -d` should work.

> -d
> Normally, when no `<path>` is specified, git clean will not recurse into untracked directories to avoid removing too much. Specify -d to have it recurse into such directories as well...
>
> source: `git help clean`  Blockquote

Answer (score 2):

- go to another (empty) folder
- run git init .
- checkout your branch there